# Correct way of drawing random number for a simulation

Tags: r, random, statistics, probability, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to generate random numbers for a simulation (the example below uses the uniform distribution for simplicity). Why would these two methods produce different average values (`a: 503.2999, b: 497.5372`) when sampled 10k times with the same seed number:

```
set.seed(2)

a <- runif(10000, 1, 999)

draw <- function(x) {
  runif(1, 1, 999)
}

b <- sapply(1:10000, draw)
print(c(mean(a), mean(b)))
```

In my model, the random number for the first method would be referenced within a simulation using a[sim_number] while in the second instance, the `runif` function would be placed inside the simulation function itself. Is there a correct way of doing it?

Comment: You have to reset the seed after the first random draw.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @joran

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the answer is that you need to set the seed before each random draw if you want them to be the same.